# Illegal remote method in java

Tags: java, rmi, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception

It's the first time I use java Rmi*. I have a custom class which extends `UnicastRemoteObject` and implements an interface which extends remote. I think that I have implemented the methods of the interface correctly in the class but still I get an `IllegalArgumentException` when I try to run my code (and it's about a method which has no arguments).

The jvm claims to have encountered an illegal remote method but the method and its implementation seem fine to me.

Is there any other reason as a result of which this exception might occur except for implementing or calling the method wrongly?

---

Here's the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: null
java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface; nested exception is:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract java.lang.String Node.getId()
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at NodeImpl.<init>(NodeImpl.java:30)
        at NodeLauncher.main(NodeLauncher.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract java.lang.String Node.getId()
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.checkMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.getRemoteInterfaces(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.getRemoteInterfaces(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Here's the interface:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

interface Node extends Remote
{
    public boolean isAlive();

    public LinkedList<NodeImpl> getLeafNodes();

    public LinkedList<NodeImpl> getNeighborhoodList();

    public String [] getRoutingTable();

    public NodeImpl initiation(String credentials,Object application);

        public String route(String message,String key);

        public void inform(byte [] id);

        public String getId();

        public boolean isConnected();

        public void applicationClose();

        public boolean distanceMeasure();
}
```

and here's the constructor of the class:

```
public NodeImpl() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
        l=4;
        M=1;
        nodeId=new byte [16];
        Random r=new Random();
        r.nextBytes(nodeId);
        leafNodes=new LinkedList<NodeImpl>();
        connected=false;
        ng=new NodeGUI(this);

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            leafNodes.add(null);
        }

        neighborhoodList=new LinkedList<NodeImpl>();
        anyNodeWhoAnswered=new LinkedList<byte []>();
        it=new InformingTimer(this);
        Thread informingTimerThread=new Thread(it);
        informingTimerThread.start();

        try 
        {
            Naming.rebind("rmi://" + "localhost" + ":1099/"+nodeId, this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(NodeImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        bootstrap();
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you managed to connect your RMI registry and look up your remote object, right? Can you provide stacktrace (on client / server)?

Comment: Stacktrace and some code might help with answering this.

Comment: The exception happens before I even try to bind the remote object.It happens at the line of the remote object's constructor where I call UnicastRemoteObject's constructor with super().I just checked the api and saw that UnicastRemoteObject has a constructor with no arguments so I don't understand what's wrong there.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

All of the methods on a RMI `Remote` interface must declare `RemoteException` in their `throws` clause, e.g.:

```
public String getId() throws RemoteException;
```

It's not clear why the exception names `getId()` specifically, it's probably just the first method it checked.

Also, the `getLeafNodes()` and `getNeighborhoodList()` methods should have return types that specify `Node`, not `NodeImpl`, otherwise they will likely fail also.

Comment: why does it needs to be included...what's the mechanism behind this..?

Comment: @guru_001 So that the RMI runtime can throw it, for errors originating within RMI rather than the remote object.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an option to use a variant of RemoteException that was unchecked. It makes it hard to use an existing interface as a remote service.