# java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface

Tags: java, guice, rmi

Getting this error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract java.util.List com.mycompany.repository.CustomCodeRepository.getCustomCodeEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  at com.mycompany.repository.impl.CustomCodeRepositoryImpl.<init>(CustomCodeRepositoryImpl.java:63)
  while locating com.mycompany.repository.impl.CustomCodeRepositoryImpl
  at com.mycompany.guice.GuiceConfigModule.configure(GuiceConfigModule.java:79)
  while locating com.mycompany.repository.CustomCodeRepository
    for field at com.mycompany.resource.ServerResource.customCodeRepository(ServerResource.java:53)
  while locating com.mycompany.resource.ServerResource
```

For this code:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
  
bind(EntityRepository.class).to(EntityRepositoryImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);  
bind(CustomCodeRepository.class).to(CustomCodeRepositoryImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
}
```

```
public class CustomCodeRepositoryImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject
        implements CustomCodeRepository {

  @Inject
  @Named("xodusRoot")
  String xodusRoot;

  @Inject
  @Named("masterStore")
  String masterStore;

  @Inject 
  EntityRepository entityRepository;

  public CustomCodeRepositoryImpl() throws RemoteException {
  }

  @Override
  public String createCustomCode(String appId, String namespace, String customCodeName, String description, Long timeout, InputStream jar) {
  }
  @Override
  public List<Map<String, Comparable>> getCustomCodeEntity(String appId, String namespace, String customCodeName) {
    return entityRepository.getEntity(
            appId,
            namespace,
            Constants.ENTITYSTORE_CUSTOMCODE,
            Constants.CUSTOMCODE_NAME,
            customCodeName,
            new ArrayList<>());
  }
```

Comment: Where is the `CustomRemoteRepository` interface mentioned in the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guice mention in its exception, it is a nested exception. The inner exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract java.util.List com.mycompany.repository.CustomCodeRepository.getCustomCodeEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

I'd guess that you are overriding `java.rmi.Remote`. If that is the case, so I'll quote from [Illegal remote method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650161/2359227):

> All of the methods on a RMI Remote interface must declare RemoteException in their throws clause.

That means that you need to add `throws RemoteException` to the declaration of all methods in the interface that is extending `Remote`. That is probably `CustomCodeRepository`.

Comment: Quite correct. OP should have included the interface in his post.